# Debugging javascript/jquery: Expecting more source characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services, jquery-ui

I am trying to work on a javascript file as a plugin to the jquery ui datepicker. Basically I have a database table representing reservations for a holiday and I people can pick dates out of the datepicker calendar. I am trying to disable selecting any days that have already been booked in a reservation. Here is my javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#checkin").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
    altField: '#date_in',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: markInvalidDates,
    onChangeMonthYear: fetchFreeDays,
    firstDay: 1 // rows starts on Monday
});

$("#checkout").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
    altField: '#date_out',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    onChangeMonthYear: fetchFreeDays,
    firstDay: 1 // rows starts on Monday
});
```

});

```
var invalidDays = [];

function getReservations() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "MullinsBayServices.asmx/GetVerifiedReservations",
data: "{}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
async: "false",
success: function(response) {
    var unvailableDates = response.d;
    $.each(unvailableDates, function(index, date) {
        invalidDays.push(date);
    });
},
failure: function(msg) {
    $('#output').text(msg);
}
```

});

```
function markInvalidDates(date) {
getReservations();
dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
if ($.inArray(dmy, invalidDays) == -1) {
    return [true, ""];
} else {
    return [false,"","Unavailable"];
}
```

}

I'm still kind of new to javascript/jquery and can't figure out where I am going wrong here. Assuming that the webservice returns the dates properly serialized in JSON does this right for what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: The "Expecting more source characters" message probably comes from the JSON parser, but we'd either have to see a running version of see the actual JSON response to offer more info.

Comment: Also, setting `async` to `false` is a pretty bad user experience (it locks up the browser during the ajax call) and it would be `async: false` not `async: "false"` so you aren't even setting it correctly.

Comment: The javascript is never even hitting my service due to the expecting more source characters error, so I don't think it could be anything due to the JSON response. As per user experience, this will occur when they click on a text box connected to the jquery datepicker so I can't see any other way that I could populate invalid days without having at least some time for that to happen. If there is an easier way to accomplish this, possibly using existing .net controls or anyting like that I am definitely open to suggestion.

Comment: You need to use debugging tools to figure exactly which line of code is causing the error message.  You can either use a debugger and step through the code and see where it occurs or you can sprinkle console.log(xxx) statements throughout and figure out which statements the error comes in between.  For example, do you know if it's coming from your ajax call or from the calendar code?  You have to narrow that down - we can't do that for you.

Comment: You can also comment out one piece of code at a time and see if that makes the msg disappear.

Comment: It was a missing closing brace at the end of the getReservations function. Sorry for bothering people with such an obvious error. Now to see if everything else actually works....

Comment: It works! Thanks for your help jfriend. Never thought I was gonna get those dates filtered properly :P Only problem now is that the app is making an ajax call for every single day in the month (30 calls) when the calendar opens so I gotta break out the function that populates my list of invalid dates. Even with 30 calls though the response happens in under a second with async set to false so once I fix that I don't think there will be any user experience issues.